# How to page through all messages in a discord channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to get all the messages in a channel but I want to do it in batches if possible.
I can see that I can set a limit (for example `limit=200`) but then is there a way to get the next 200 after that set of 200, etc?
Basically is there a way to implement pagination over the message history?

I tried to use `Limit=None` (and that works) but if there are 1000s of messages in a server this could cause issues, hence I was wondering if I can use some sort of pagination

Comment: You could use the [`before`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=messages#discord.TextChannel.history) argument for this.

Comment: There's no cursor or continuation token you can use. Use your limit 200, keep track of the extremal message ID, and then in the subsequent query use `before` or `after` to set where the next frame should be aligned.  Repeat until empty

Comment: Ah thanks - I had though the before and after were only datetimes - didn't realise you could also use message IDs too - brilliant.